# Creating an HTML output in R that has table with video

Tags: r, video, r-markdown

I am currently trying to take a table I have, which each row corresponds to a video, say from the column P = 1:nrow, and the videos are titled 1.mp4, 2.mp4.. n.mp4. I am trying to create an HTML file that contains this table, and when a row (or cell) is clicked on it plays the video (videos are short (30 sec max)). I have currently tried

`````
````
library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)
require(tidyverse)
require(htmltools)

data <- read_csv("path/to/data.csv")

data <- data %>% head(8) %>% 
  mutate(P = 1:8) %>%
  select(P, Pitcher, TaggedPitchType, RelSpeed, Tilt, SpinRate,
         InducedVertBreak, HorzBreak, Extension, RelHeight, RelSide)

html_file <- "bullpen_data.html"


datatable <- datatable(
  data, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10),
  callback = JS("
    table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
      var rowData = table.row(this).data();
      var videoEmbed = document.getElementById('video_embed');
      // Replace 'G:/My Drive/EdgerTM Tool/test video/' with the correct folder path
      var videoPath = 'path/to/video/' + rowData[1] + '.mp4';
      videoEmbed.src = videoPath;
    });
  ")
)

# Create the HTML code to embed the video
video_code <- sprintf(
  '<iframe style="display:none;" id="video_embed" src=""></iframe>'
)

# Combine everything into a standalone HTML file
html_code <- c(
  "<html>",
  "<head>",
  tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatable@1.11.3/dist/datatables.min.js"),
  tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", href = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/datatable@1.11.3/dist/datatables.min.css"),
  "</head>",
  "<body>",
  as.character(datatable),
  video_code,
  "</body>",
  "</html>"
)

# Write the HTML code to a file
writeLines(paste(html_code, collapse = "\n"), con = html_file)
````
`````

But that has produced an html with just the text, with no table nor video. I have also tried in RMarkdown with

`````
```
---
title: "Baseball Bullpen Report"
output: html_document
---
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE)

library(DT)
library(htmlwidgets)
require(tidyverse)
require(htmltools)
data <- read_csv("path/to/data.csv)

data <- data %>% head(8) %>% 
  mutate(P = 1:8) %>%
  select(P, Pitcher, TaggedPitchType, RelSpeed, Tilt, SpinRate,
         InducedVertBreak, HorzBreak, Extension, RelHeight, RelSide)

datatable <- datatable(
  data, rownames = FALSE, options = list(pageLength = 10),
  callback = JS("
    table.on('click.dt', 'tr', function() {
      var rowData = table.row(this).data();
      var videoEmbed = document.getElementById('video_embed');
      var videoPath = 'path/to/video/' + rowData[1] + '.mp4';
      videoEmbed.src = videoPath;
    });
  ")
)

# Create the HTML code to embed the video
video_code <- sprintf(
  '<iframe style="display:none;" id="video_embed" src=""></iframe>'
)

# Save the rendered HTML output
html_file <- "bullpen_data.html"
htmltools::save_html(tagList(datatable, HTML(video_code)), file = html_file)
````
`````

I am totally open for different ways to display this/save this information. All the videos and data are stored locally, and I am looking for a way to send this out to people. Any advice is much appreciated.

Comment: I don't know if your problem is solved but if not, then... **(1)** It might help to just use R to create a string of HTML content and then save that String as an `.html` file. You can create [HTML5 tables](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) within the HTML text but populate some of its text content (titles. links, etc) from your extracted data (_eg:_ from the CSV file?)... **(2)** For making text tags like `<span>` or `<text>` to be clickable you can use [onClick](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ev_onclick.asp) where you set it to run a JS function (also defined within your text).

Comment: PS: I don't use R so try something like: `my_html_out <- '<!DOCTYPE html> <html lang=\"en\"> <head> <title> My R HTML page <\/title> <\/head> <\/html>'` then save/send that `my_html_out ` string as html for display in a browser. The title of the tab/window should be "_My R HTML page_". PPS: You might need to ask a new question focusing on outputting the correct HTML text based on your CSV input.